# How to download a zip file in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a following problem. I want to download a zip file. See a following code:

```
import os
import requests
import time


url = "https://kriminalita.policie.cz/api/v1/downloads/202011.csv.zip"
name = url.split("/")[-1]

response = requests.get(url)

with open(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\misak\Desktop\LD_save\stazene', name), 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(response.content))
```

The zip file seems to be downloaded, however I am not able to open it, because "is either in unknown format or damaged". But when I put my url into Chrome and try it manually I am able to open the zip file in WinRAR. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to download file with url and save to a specific location, use `urlretrieve` would be better:

```
import urllib.request

print('Beginning file download with urllib2...')

url = 'http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/Users/scott/Downloads/cat.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are writing the contents of a zip file (which are binary) as a string.
Check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/3083470) how to write a binary file you received with `requests.get()`